# LinqToExcel ignore certain columns from StrictMapping

Tags: c#, exception, mapping, ace, linq-to-excel

I am reading Excel file using `LinqToExcel`:

```
var Excel = new ExcelQueryFactory(Filename);

Excel.databaseEngine = DatabaseEngine.Ace;

Excel.strictMapping = true;
```

I want to exclude certain columns, to prevent the strict mapping feature from throwing an exception for those columns.

Answer (score 3):

What if you set `StrictMapping` to false? Will that work for you?